# Obtener registro único con la FechaRecepcionContrato agrupado por IdEmpresa

Tags: sql-server

¿Me podríais, por favor, ayudar en la siguiente consulta?

Tengo la siguiente query interna en la cual deseo obtener un único registro por IdEmpresa en la cual me traiga únicamente el registro que tenga la FechaRecepcionContrato más alta:

```
SELECT MAX(IdVentas) AS IdVentas, V.IdEmpresa AS IdEmpresa, MAX(V.IdProducto) AS IdProducto, MAX(V.FechaRecepcionContrato) AS FechaRecepcionContrato FROM [Ventas] V
WHERE ISNULL(V.FechaRecepcionContrato,'') <>''
GROUP BY V.IdEmpresa, V.IdProducto
ORDER BY V.IdEmpresa, MAX(V.FechaRecepcionContrato) DESC
```

[image: Resultados Query interna]

Posteriormente pretendo enlazar ese registro único con mi tabla de Empresas:

```
Select * from Empresas E
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT MAX(IdVentas) AS IdVentas, V.IdEmpresa AS IdEmpresa, MAX(V.IdProducto) AS IdProducto, MAX(V.FechaRecepcionContrato) AS FechaRecepcionContrato FROM [Ventas] V
    WHERE ISNULL(V.FechaRecepcionContrato,'') <>''
    GROUP BY V.IdEmpresa, V.IdProducto
    ORDER BY V.IdEmpresa, MAX(V.FechaRecepcionContrato) DESC
    

) as TMP on TMP.IdEmpresa = E.IdEmpresa
```

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: En la primera query, para que agrupas por `max(v.fechaRecepcionContrato)`. No tiene sentido agrupar por una columna que lo que queremos es aplicarle una función de agrupamiento. Elimínalo del group by.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT IdVentas, IdEmpresa, IdProducto, FechaRecepcionContrato, IdEstado
    FROM (
        SELECT IdVentas, IdEmpresa, IdProducto, FechaRecepcionContrato, IdEstado, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdEmpresa ORDER BY FechaRecepcionContrato DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM Ventas
        WHERE FechaRecepcionContrato IS NOT NULL
    ) AS Subquery
    WHERE RowNumber = 1
) as TMP on TMP.IdEmpresa = E.IdEmpresa
```

Gracias